# Why am I not getting the innerText property of an element?

Tags: javascript, cypress, google-search, innertext

I am trying to retrieve the string for the number of google searches in order to use it with a cypress test.
[image: Google search results]

This is the code I am trying to use to get it.
It retrieves null.

```
let text = cy.get('#result-stats').innerText
    cy.log(text)
```

I have also tried with several other methods, like innerHtml or textContent.
I have tried getting the whole div, invoking the text, invoking the val, getting the children...
Nothing works...

What I want to get is the string "About 8.200.000.000.000 results". At this point I don't care if the HTML syntax is present or not, I just want the number.

Comment: Maybe it does not load immediately. Try to set some timeout and see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypress commands will yield their results wrapped in a `Chainable`, so trying to set a variable equal to `cy.get().innerText` won't work - `cy.get()` does not yield a variable with `innerText`. Instead, you can  use closures to set the value of your `text` variable.

```js
let text = "";
cy.get('#result-stats')
  .invoke('text') // grab the text directly 
  .then((value) => {
    text = value // set the variable `text` equal to the yielded `value`
  }).then(() => {
    cy.log(text); // log text in a separate .then because of how cy.log enqueues
  });
```

Now, you might be looking at that and think "oh, I can just use `cy.get().invoke('text')`. But, again, that would yield a `Chainable<String>` variable, and not a `String` variable.

There are additional strategies to use for getting the text value of an element on the screen, depending on your use case. The above works for the method you outlined in the original question, but may not work in a more elaborate use case.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `text = value` instead of `text = then`?

Comment: It worked!! Thank you very much!!

I didn't know about the way cypress wraps in chainables, this will help me in the future and with some flaky tests I had before.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to adjust the timeout of the `cy.get('#result-stats')` to get the element from the page.

After that, it's a matter of parsing the element text to a number.
I recommend using regex `/About (.+) results/` where `(.+)` represents the number portion, and `[1]` at the end gives you that as the output.

`cy.log()` inside the callback is asynchronous, so you should use the synchronous version `Cypress.log()`.

```js
cy.intercept({ resourceType: /xhr|fetch/ }, { log: false })

cy.visit('https://google.com');

cy.get('[title="Search"]')
  .type('Municipality of Laz Rozas de Madrid')
  .type('{enter}')

cy.get('#result-stats', {timeout:20_000})
  .then((results) => {
    const text = results.text()
    const countAsText = text.match(/About (.+) results/)[1]
    const count = +countAsText.replaceAll(',', '')
    Cypress.log({displayName: 'Results count', message: count})
    return count
  })
  .should('be.gt', 1_000_000)
```

Result:

[image: Cypress test log]

Comment: Hi.

I tried this code and count === "NaN". However, there were some things I changed. I am in Spain so instead of search Chrome displayed "Buscar" in the bar, and I had to change the text.match to (/Aproximadamente (.+) resultados/)[1]  

The rest was left as it is in your answer, and I think my changes should not interfere in the code you wrote

Comment: NaN means you missed the `+` conversion. I don't think it has anything to do with being Spanish, but it's possible :)